# React Native switchNavigator and createBottomTabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I am working with React Native `createBottomTabNavigator` and see that:

> lazy - Defaults to true. If false, all tabs are rendered immediately. When true, tabs are rendered only when they are made active for the first time. Note: tabs are not re-rendered upon subsequent visits.
>   https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/

Where do I put the attribute "lazy" and set it to false if I want to reload the Connection page every time I click on the **Connect navigation tab**?

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import ...

const RegisterScreens = createSwitchNavigator({
  Phone: PhoneLoginScreen,
  Register: RegisterScreen
});

const switchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  SplashScreen,
  TutotialScreen,
  loginFlow: createStackNavigator({
      Main: MainScreen,
      EmailLogin: EmailLoginScreen,
      PhoneLogin: RegisterScreens
    }),
    mainFlow: createBottomTabNavigator({
      Home: createStackNavigator({
        HomeScreen,
        AccountScreen
      }),
      Connect : ConnectionsScreen,
      Chat: createStackNavigator({
        AllChatScreen,
        SingleChat
      })
    })
});

const App = createAppContainer(switchNavigator);
export default() => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
        <App ref={(navigator)=> {setNavigator(navigator)}}/>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
};
```

I am using hooks and want to reload the Connection page because of a callout happening in `useEffect()`

Comment: Did you find anything?